# ESRI Javascript Web Application Hosted on Amazon Web Services

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, web-mapping, proxy, amazon-web-services

I have just deployed my first web application to Amazon S3.  This web application is a simple web mapping app using the ESRI Javascript API and consuming a web map from ArcGIS Online.

I have been having issues with this application because of the proxy page.  According to the help, in order to use ArcGIS Online web maps, you have to set up a proxy page.  I didn't do that and when I was developing the application, most components worked without issues in Chrome and Firefox.  Lately though, I have noticed that the application, which supports editing, does not apply edits from Internet Explorer.  The console gives an error message explaining that it is trying to reach a url through the proxy page and is not succeeding because the proxy page does not exist.  As far as I know, S3 does not support this proxy page because it requires an application like PHP or ASP.Net.

Has anyone had any experience with this?  I am thinking my next step may be to try and deploy this web application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk instead.  Has anyone had any luck with that?

Comment: Did you check this ?http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/12/05/deploying-web-mapping-apps-on-amazon-s3/

Comment: + What software platform you are suing (10 or 10.1 if 10.1 then did you configure web adapter ?)

Comment: I'm not technically using any software on my end other than plain old html, javascript, and css.  The data is all hosted on ArcGIS Online.  We do not have our own ArcGIS Server instance running.  I have seen the blog article before, in fact that is why I put it on S3 in the first place.  However, because we are using ArcGIS Online instead of our own server, I don't have anything on EC2 right now.

Comment: This related question might interest you: [Route an HTTP request through a Python function (on the way to/from AGOL)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370869/route-an-http-request-through-a-python-function-on-the-way-to-from-agol). And this one too: [HTTP request -to- AWS Lambda Python function -to- AGOL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370869/route-an-http-request-through-a-python-function-on-the-way-to-from-agol).

Answer (score 4):

I've been experimenting with AWS lately. S3 doesn't support server-side scripting -- see below. I think you want beanstalk or just a regular EC2 server. I'm running a micro linux EC2 server essentially for free right now. It's "on demand" instead of "reserved", but I just keep it on all the time. I think the advantage of beanstalk is that you have many preconfigured options ready versus manually configuring an EC2 server. With beanstalk, you could just choose an apache setup with php and then upload the php proxy with your wesite. Versus stuff like starting Apache, opening firewall, getting public IP from Amazon, etc.

This issue brings up another question though, after reading through Esri docs and having problems with proxys and security -- I don't know why arcgis api still wants/needs to use a proxy. I don't know why it can't POST to CORS enabled servers like arcgis.com or whatever server. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/xhrPost.html

"Q: What kinds of websites should I host using Amazon S3 static website hosting?
Amazon S3 is ideal for hosting websites that contain only static content, including html files, images, videos, and client-side scripts such as JavaScript. Amazon EC2 is recommended for websites with server-side scripting and database interaction." http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#What_kinds_of_websites_should_I_host_using_Amazon_S3_static_website_hosting

Comment: This related question might interest you: [Route an HTTP request through a Python function (on the way to/from AGOL)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370869/route-an-http-request-through-a-python-function-on-the-way-to-from-agol). And this one too: [HTTP request -to- AWS Lambda Python function -to- AGOL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370891/http-request-to-aws-lambda-python-function-to-agol).