# HTTP request -to- AWS Lambda Python function -to- AGOL

Tags: python, arcgis-online, amazon-web-services, http, lambda

I want to make an HTTP GET request to AGOL, but I want to route the request through a Python function.

Since I can't host the Python function on AGOL [(more info here)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/370872/135445), I'd like to use AWS-Lambda instead.

`HTTP GET request` ➔ `AWS Lambda Python function` ➔ `AGOL`

What would it take to configure AWS Lambda so that it can serve as a middle tier between the HTTP GET request and AGOL?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample AWS Lambda setup from a colleague:

1. Create an AWS account (free).
2. In AWS Lambda, create a new function.

   - Enter a `function name` and `Runtime` ➔ `Python 3.7`
3. Write the function.

   - This sample script receives an `ASSET_ID` value from a URL, processes it with Python, and sends additional requests to AGOL. It returns a JSON dictionary.

---

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import json


# Get a security token to append to all requests
def GetToken():
    username = '<my username>'
    password = '<my password>'

    url = 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/generateToken' 
    post_fields = {'username': username,'password':password,'expiration':'60','client':'referer','referer':'http://www.arcgis.com','f':'json' }

    request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
    out = urlopen(request).read().decode()
    resp_dict = json.loads(out)
    # print (resp_dict['token'])
    return resp_dict['token']


# Query a feature service with a where clause returning all fields.  Function returns a json dictionary
def queryFeatureService(url,token,where):

    post_fields = {'token': token,'where':where,'outfields':'*','returngeometry':'false','f':'json' }

    request = Request(url, urlencode(post_fields).encode())
    out = urlopen(request).read().decode()
    resp_dict = json.loads(out)
    return resp_dict


# Get the zone value from the matching Active Transportation feature  
def GetZone(jsonFeatures,zoneField):

    for feature in jsonFeatures['features']:
        # print (feature['attributes']['ZONE_'])
        return feature['attributes'][zoneField]


# Query with ASSET_ID, returning the workorder record with a new "ZONE_" field added from the matching Transportation layer
# 'lambda_handler' is the main function for Lambda.  Code starts here when called
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    urlWorkorders = 'https://services.arcgis.com/Akv3yjcvcvmR0q1R/ArcGIS/rest/services/<my AGOL account name>/FeatureServer/0/query' 
    urlActiveTransportationPoints = 'https://services.arcgis.com/Akv3yjcvcvmR0q1R/ArcGIS/rest/services/Active_Transportation_Points/FeatureServer/0/query'

    token = GetToken()   
    ASSET_ID = event["queryStringParameters"]['asset_id']
  
    jsonWorkorder = queryFeatureService(urlWorkorders, token,"ASSET_ID = '" + ASSET_ID + "'")

    # JSON for the new "ZONE_" field, appends to return Workorder JSON object to give it this missing field
    fldZone = {'name':'ZONE_','type':'esriFieldTypeString','alias':'ZONE_','sqlType':'sqlTypeOther','length':15,'domain':None,'defaultValue':None}
    jsonWorkorder['fields'].append(fldZone)

    # Query the Active Transportation points with the same ASSET_ID
    jsonActiveTransportation = queryFeatureService(urlActiveTransportationPoints,token,"ASSET_ID = '" + ASSET_ID + "'")

    # Get the ZONE_ value
    zone = GetZone(jsonActiveTransportation,'ZONE_')

    # Set the ZONE_ value in the ZONE_ field that was added to workorders
    jsonWorkorder['features'][0]['attributes']['ZONE_'] = zone
    # return (jsonWorkorder)
    return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : '*'
        
        },
        'body': json.dumps(jsonWorkorder)
    }
```

---

4. Choose `Add Trigger` ➔ `API Gateway`
5. Choose `Create a new API`, `REST API`, `Security` ➔ `Open`
6. Open `API Gateway`: `workorder-API hyperlink`
7. `Actions` ➔ `Create method` ➔ `GET` ➔ configure as follows:

   - [image]
   - `Save`
8. Click `Method Request` header link ➔ expand `Query String Parameters`
9. Add query string `"asset_id"`

---

**Conclusion:**

It's a pretty interesting solution that could be useful for people who have similar requirements.

- I have more detailed instructions with screen captures in a PDF. If anyone wants it, just ask.
- I have a related question here: [Query an ArcGIS Online FC via an HTTP request](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/368283/135445)

---

**A note about security:**

The AWS Lambda function specifies/stores the AGOL username and password. This freaked me out at first.

However, since the username and password are server-side, they are never exposed to the client user.

- In theory, we could write this same function as an AJAX call in JavaScript, but we would need to embed the credentials in the web code, making it unsecure, so that's why a server-side function is needed.
- Additionally, we could alter the Lambda function to pass an AGOL-registered app's clientID and Secret for more granular access control—which would not have my username and password embedded in the function.
- More info here: [ArcGIS Web AppBuilder (Developer Edition)](https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/guide/getstarted.htm). See the "Provide an app ID for Web AppBuilder" section (not just limited to just WAB, but for any app that needs a ClientID and Secret).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer above but do you need to install any specific libraries or other tools to get it to run in AWS?

Comment: I got help from a developer I know. So he'd have to answer that question.